# Wordpress и localhost

Tags: javascript, wordpress, angularjs

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может ли быть такое, что код, написанный на AngularJS отлично работает на встроенном локальном сервере Webstorm, а при переносе его на Wordpress - он перестает работать?

Comment: В консоли есть ошибки? А в панели Network?

Comment: @br3t Нет, вообще никаких ошибок. Это-то и ставит в тупик.

Comment: Попробуйте повставлять `console.log`и, чтобы убедиться, что ваши файлы скриптов подключаются

Comment: @br3t Так работает при первом вызове функции. На втором вызове по кнопке все валится. Хотя, console.log показывает, что все сработало и переменные поменяли значения.